# Can Windows CMD/DOS Commands Be Used In An OpenSSL Configuration File On Windows 10?

Tags: openssl

I'm using OpenSSL v1.1.1g on a Windows 10 machine (I don't know Linux - yet).  Can Windows CMD/DOS commands be used in the OpenSSL configuration file or is the configuration file limited to the use of OpenSSL commands only?  I assume the answer to this question is "No" since OpenSSL uses its own parser to process OpenSSL configuration files, but I'd like to have my assumption confirmed.

Comment: You are correct - it cannot. However, what you can do is use a batch file (or PowerShell) to dynamically write your OpenSSL configuration file, before getting it to run `openssl.exe`.  It may help if you were to expand on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, garethTheRed for the answer.  I am trying to understand how I might be able to use Windows CMD/DOS to provide the parameters to OpenSSL command options (e.g., the directory path to the 'req' command's -out option) so that I don't have to manually create a complicated OpenSSL command line everytime I want to use OpenSSL.  I also want to use Windows CMD/DOS to provide additional default behavior functionality for various OpenSSL commands.  I will use your suggestion to "dynamically write your OpenSSL configuration file."  If you change your comment to an answer I'll give you credit.